# Which version of eclipse should i download?

Tags: java, eclipse, struts

I'd like to learn struts2 with eclipse. Which version of eclipse should i download?

My background is as a c# developer, so i don't really know much at all about java but i'm keen to learn.

I'm looking on the eclipse site http://eclipse.org/downloads/ and i think what i want is one of these, but i'm not sure:

- Eclipse for Java EE developers
- Eclipse for Java developers
- Classic Eclipse

I've done a bit of searching around, and most tutorials seem to assume you've already got everything installed. I'm starting with nothing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts is a web framework built on top of JSP/Servlet API. Get **Eclipse for Java EE**. It ships with all plugins needed for web development, under each the great [WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) and several default appserver plugins. The normal Eclipse version lacks this.

When starting a project, first integrate the appserver in your Eclipse environment through the `Servers` view (obviously you need to download and install the appserver in question in your platform first, then it's just a matter of pointing its installation path, I can recommend using [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org)). Then create a `Dynamic Web Project`, pick the integrated appserver from the list and go ahead! :)

Comment: One thing to note: I struggled for hours today but finally discovered you need to set the 'dynamic web module version' to 2.4 when creating the new project, otherwise it does not work and gives a cryptic error.

Comment: Also found this tutorial is about the only one that worked for me!

http://www.howtodothings.com/computers-internet/how-to-create-struts-2-helloworld-on-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse for Java Developers is sufficient for your needs.  The EE functionality isn't required to use Struts.  I also recommend using Jetty for a web container and Maven for dependency management.

Oh, and you should install the JDK first of course.  Get the latest JDK 6 build.  Not one of the bundles, just the JDK, which is listed below the bundles on this [page](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp)

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the Eclipse Java EE version is good for Web stuff.  It knows about WAR files which you will need to actually run your struts code.  The major hurdle is getting all the used libraries placed so they end up in WEB-INF/lib.